# What could "touch the incongruous" mean? (from an old story)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Reading an old story by A. Blackwood, I stumbled upon the following sentence (for the context, the woman is said to have some kind of second sight):

> And the idea of this motherly, sedate, and wholesome woman, absorbed
> day and night in prosaic domestic duties, and yet ‘seeing’ things,
> touched the incongruous almost to the point of alarm.

I cannot fully understand the last part: touched the incongruous almost to the point of alarm. I thought it was a phrase (if something touches the incongruous) but I was wrong.

Comment: "touch" can mean to "just reach" or to "come close to" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer is juxtaposing the homely features of an ordinary woman— **motherly, sedate, and wholesome woman**,... **prosaic domestic duties** with the extraordinary gift she possesses— **and yet seeing things**— Probably, hence the *incongruity.* Why it should be *to the point of alarm* would possibly be understood fully from further context. Perhaps, people around her took liberties with her, made fun of her, and so forth; and the sudden epiphany or knowledge that she was more than just a factotum caused in these people a sense of alarm. But this is just guesswork.

Comment: Also worth noting, *incongruous* is normally an adjective but serves as a noun here.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin— Indeed! Like in the case of _the rich_/ the poor_, etc.